# Sin & Cos Equation/Relation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

If sin(x) = 0.3, find cos(pi-x)

how i would solve this:

- let x = sin-1(0.3)
- solve for cos(pi-[sin-1(0.3)])

Is there a way to solve this by hand?

Is the above method wrong?

Comment: See, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Symmetry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sin x=0.3$,
$$\cos(\pi-x)=-\cos(x)=\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}=\pm\frac{\sqrt{91}}{10}$$

Comment: so this needs to be solved on a calculator

Comment: No, $-\sqrt{1-0.3^2}=-\sqrt{1-9/100}=-\sqrt{91/100}=..$. @confused

Comment: @impartialmale, why do you assume the range?

Comment: @TooOldForMath, $$\cos x=\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2x},$$ right?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Okie!!! $|\cos x|=\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$

Comment: @TooOldForMath, $$\sin x=0.3,$$  means $x$ may lie in first or in second quadrant, right?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Yes, total confusion, thanks!

Comment: 1-9/100 does not equal 9/10 ...

Comment: if x can lie in the first or sec quadrant shouldn't the range be < pi ... not pi/2

Comment: @confused: Update the page.

Comment: why is it plus/minus ... not just minus??

Comment: Because, if $\sin x=0.3$, there is two values possible for $x$ in $[0,2\pi)$, on one of them $\cos$ is negative and on one it is positive. @confused

Comment: oh okay! if x is in the first quadrant, then do we say only plus ?

Comment: Yes. @confused.

Answer (score 1):

$$cos(\pi-x)=sin\pi sin x+cos\pi cos x=0+cos\pi cos x=-cos x= -\sqrt{1-sin^2 x}\; (0\leq x\leq \pi/2)$$